# Implementation of Enum

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to do a bit of reverse engineering on enum.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        num number=num.one;
        System.out.println(number); //outputs result as one

    }
}

enum num{
    one;
}
```

Now how do I implement the same without using enum.

```
public class Lab24a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        num1 num= num1.one;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}

class num1{
    public static final num1 one= new num1();

    private num1(){
    }

    public String toString(){
        return //how to implement the two string totally lost here.
    }
}
```

I was able to write a code until this, but I am not able to printout the value, please give me your suggestions or hints. I even tried looking at the following links.

[Confusion with Enum type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802541/confusion-with-enum-type/7802635#7802635)

[enum implementation inside interface - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318796/enum-implementation-inside-interface-java)

Comment: When i am trying to use num again, i am getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use an `enum`? IMO Java is missing some key features, but one of the things it does right it is the way it uses enums.

If you really want to avoid an `enum`, you could do this:

```
class num1{
    public static final num1 one= new num1("one");

    private String name;
    private num1(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override  //Be sure to add the override annotation here!
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I am not passing anything in my constructor, its a default one.

Comment: I understand the benefits, I just wanted to understand things in much depth, so trying to learn. I even tried reading the generated class file, but it showed nothing, just enum and the code.

Comment: This is your code, so you're free to change the constructor, right? I don't see a better way to solve your problem than the solution I posted. The bottom line with Java enums is that each member (such as `one` in your example) is a full-blown object on its own.

Comment: here even we have created an object right. using the new keyword, and I was trying to mimic it.